# How to disable SSLv3 for POODLE attack

Tags: security, windows-server-2003, tomcat, internet-security, client-server

I want to Disable SSLv3 to restrict the POODLE attack on my website

My website is hosted on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 System

I am using Apache Tomcat as an application server with thee version Java 7

(I have tried registry level changes and restarted the system but it wasn't helpful.)

Please suggest any solution for Disabling SSLv3

Comment: You do know that the 'attack' is hyped? You need an active man in the middle who would *also* have to have access to the user's browser and at that moment the user is a victim anyway - there is no need for the attacker to waste his time poodling further. Read https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-478.txt or listen to [Episode 478 of Security Now](https://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm)

Comment: Thanks.. I have changed Tomcat configuration file and solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable SSL V3 by adding `sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"` to server.xml file in Apache Tomcat folder. Settings will be varied according to different versions. you will get more info from [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/POODLE), [here](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2014/10/poodle-attack-and-disabling-ssl-v3-in.html) and [server fault QA site](https://serverfault.com/questions/637649/how-do-i-disable-sslv3-support-in-apache-tomcat)

Comment: Thanks.. I have changed Tomcat configuration file and solved the issue